# comparing/copying largest files to new folder

Tags: vbscript

What I wish to do is:

1. Copy files from a variety of sub-folders under a single main folder to a destination folder.
2. Three options when copying:

   1. If no file in destination folder exists then copy.
   2. If file exists, copy over if filesize is larger than destination file.
   3. If file exists and both are the same filesize compare date/time and copy over if most recent.

Here is my pseudocode so far:

```
Dim filesys, strSourceFile, strDestFolder, strDestFile

Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strSourceFile = S:\SoCal\Section_2\*\Autogen\texture\*.agn
strDestFolder = F:\ADDON_SCENERY\simwestSOCAL\texture
strDestFile = F:\ADDON_SCENERY\simwestSOCAL\texture\*.agn

COPY each file in strSourceFolder
If IsEmpty (SourceFile, DestFolder)
Else If (SourceFile FileSize > DestFile)
Else If (SourceFile DateTime > DestFile DateTime) 
Then 'keep/copy most recent file
End if
```

Am I on the right track?
Do I need to add a Loop?
Can one compare file sizes?  All my research has found nothing yet on this.
Can I compare Date and Time against files?

As an update to my original post... (hope I am following forum rules correctly),

I have spent the last several weeks non-stop just reading-reading-reading and testing-failure-testing.  I am happy to say (and a little proud), that I have completed my very first script... and it appears to work as planned but for just one file.  I now need to convert this to work on all files inside my 'sourcefolder'.

I am a bit "brain dead" from this so any direction on converting this would be most appreciated. I know I need loops but what type and where?  Do I rename everything referring to a file to a folder or use '*.txt' for files?  In the meantime I will keep studying.

Here is my script (yea, lot's of MsgBox's so I could follow along the script path):

```
dim dFolder 
dFolder = "S:\Scripting Workfolder\destfolder\"
dim dFile
dFile= "S:\Scripting Workfolder\destfolder\File 1.txt"
dim sFile
sFile = "S:\Scripting Workfolder\sourcefolder\File 1.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Check to see if the file already exists in the destination folder

If Not fso.FileExists(dFile) Then
    MsgBox "File does not exist - will copy over to dFolder"
    fso.CopyFile sFile, dFolder, true
    Elseif fso.FileExists(dFile) Then 
    MsgBox "File already exist in destination folder determine largest"
    ReplaceIfLarger sFile, dFile
End If

Sub ReplaceIfLarger(sFile, dFile)
    const overwrite_existing = true
    dim objFSO
    set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    dim objSourceFile  
    set objSourceFile = objFSO.GetFile(sFile)
    'dim kbSourceSize
    kbSourceSize = objSourceFile.size   

    dim objTargetFile
    set objTargetFile = objFSO.GetFile (dFile)
    'dim kbTargetSize
    kbTargetSize = objTargetFile.size

    If kbSourceSize > kbTargetSize Then
    MsgBox "Source file is LARGER and will overwrite to dest folder"
    objFSO.CopyFile objSourceFile.Path, objTargetFile.Path, overwrite_existing
    ElseIf kbSourceSize < kbTargetSize Then
    MsgBox "Source file is smaller - Will not overwrite to dest folder"
    Else
    ReplaceIfNewer sFile, dFile 
    End If
End Sub

Sub ReplaceIfNewer(sFile, dFile)
    MsgBox "Both files exist and are the same size. Keep newest file"
    const overwrite_existing = true
    dim objFSO
    set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    dim dtmSourceFile  
    set dtmSourceFile = objFSO.GetFile(sFile)

    dim dtmTargetFile
    set dtmTargetFile = objFSO.GetFile(dFile) 

    If (dtmSourceFile.DateLastModified > dtmTargetFile.DateLastModified) then
    MsgBox "Source File is Newer than Target File - Overwrite Target file"
    objFSO.CopyFile dtmSourceFile.Path, dtmTargetFile.Path, overwrite_existing
    Else 
    MsgBox "Source File is Older than Target File - Will not overwrite file"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). And yes, you need a loop. Probably more than one.

Comment: You should do a loop for each file in current folder, and make use of recursive subs for the sub-folders.